# При первом запуске combobox не применяет шрифт к label

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Использую JavaFX и Scene Builder

Имеется label,  и combobox со шрифтами. При выборе шрифта из combobox, он применятся к лейбл. Работать то combobox работает, но плохо

1.При клике на combobox список шрифтов открывается не сразу, а спустя секунду, как будто combobox тормозит.

2.При первом выборе шрифта, он не применяется к label, а применение шрифта срабатывает только если я снова кликну на combobox и выберу снова шрифт, причем другой, а не тот, который был активным.

Как можно оптимизировать код,чтобы работало все как часы?

Возможно я неправильно сделал реализацию применения шрифта к label.

[Видео](https://hdd.tomsk.ru/desk/tdluxhfn#)

```
@FXML  private ComboBox<String> fontSelector;
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;
```

При клике на combobox вызывается метод:

```
public void changeLabel(ActionEvent event) {
    //apply selected font from combobox to label
    fontSelector.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> fontLabel.setFont(Font.font(newValue, FontWeight.NORMAL, 35)));
  }

//get system fonts
  ObservableList<String> fonts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFamilies());
```

Далее:

```
@Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

//show fonts' actual look in combobox list
    fontSelector.setCellFactory((ListView<String> listView) -> {
      final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>(){
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
          super.updateItem(item, empty);
          if (item != null) {
            setText(item);
            setFont(new Font(item, 14));
          }
        }
      };
      return cell;
    });

    fontSelector.setItems(fonts);
}
```

**Редакция:**

Я изменил метод, который показывает системные шрифты в combobox, но при клике на combobox все равно задержка в секунду

```
@FXML  private ComboBox<Font> fontSelector;

//get font family and size from comboboxes
  private static Font getFont(Font font, Integer size) {
    return Font.font(font == null ? null : font.getFamily(), size == null ? -1d : size.doubleValue());
  }


//getting font families
    fontSelector.getItems().addAll(Font.getFamilies().stream().map(name -> Font.font(name, 14)).toArray(Font[]::new));

// bind font based on size/family
    fontLabel.fontProperty()
             .bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> getFont(fontSelector.getValue(), size.getValue()),
              fontSelector.valueProperty(), size.valueProperty()));


    //display font families looks in combobox
    class FontListCell extends ListCell<Font> {
      @Override
      public void updateItem(Font item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {
          setText(item.getFamily());
          setFont(item);
        } else {
          setText("");
          setFont(Font.font(12));
        }
      }
    }

    fontSelector.setCellFactory(lv -> new FontListCell());
    fontSelector.setButtonCell(new FontListCell());
  }
```

**РЕДАКЦИЯ 2:**

Я забыл написать, что проблема именно в отображении семейства шрифтов, то есть названия шрифтов, а не размеров шрифтов.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит добавлять слушатель каждый раз, когда происходит нажатие на кнопку. Обычно это делают один раз и где то заранее.

Вот рабочий пример использования ComboBox:

```
public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label fontLbl = new Label("Fonts:");
        ComboBox<String> fontBox = new ComboBox<>();
        fontBox.getItems().addAll("font1", "font2", "font3", "font4");

        Label selectionLbl = new Label("current font");

        // обработка нажатия ------------------------
        fontBox.setOnAction(e->{
            selectionLbl.setText(fontBox.getValue());
        });
        // ------------------------------------------

        HBox row1 = new HBox(10, fontLbl, fontBox);
        VBox root = new VBox(row1, selectionLbl);

        root.setSpacing(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Using ComboBox Controls");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Добавляю пример для данного случая:

```
public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label fontLbl = new Label("Fonts:");
        ComboBox<Font> fontBox = new ComboBox<>();
        fontBox.getItems().addAll(new Font(10), new Font(12) , new Font(14) , new Font(16));

        Label selectionLbl = new Label("current font");

        // обработка нажатия ------------------------
        fontBox.setOnAction(e->{
            selectionLbl.setFont(fontBox.getValue());
        });
        // ------------------------------------------

        HBox row1 = new HBox(10, fontLbl, fontBox);
        VBox root = new VBox(row1, selectionLbl);

        root.setSpacing(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600,300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Using ComboBox Controls");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я сделал редакцию, посмотрите пожалуйста, в вашем ответе combobox стринговый, и вы добавили строковые названия шрифтов, а как можно в вашем примере использовать системные шрифты, а не строковые названия?

Comment: @kentforth Добавил пример со шрифтами

Comment: в вашем примере вы поместили размеры шрифтов. Это я тоже вполне успешно реализовал, но мне нужно поместить в Combobox семьи шрифтов, которые находятся в системной папке fonts на компьютере, и чтобы их названия отражались в combobox

Comment: @kentforth Тогда переформулируйте свой вопрос. Возможно задача более сложная чем мне кажется и поэтому у Вас так много кода

Comment: сделал редакцию, возможно вы знаете как добавить свои шрифты из папки в combobox вместо системных? этот вариант бы меня тоже устроил

Comment: @kentforth Проблема в том, что в ComboBox при нажатии отображается название Font в виде некрасивой строки формата Font[name=..., family=..., ...] А хотелось что то вроде my font ?